# How to use SpEL to select and return root objects in a collection by evaluating a list of other sub-objects maintained in a field in the root objects

Tags: parsing, expression, filtering, spring-el

The service I'm working with is running in Java 8. I am using SpEL to filter a generic collection of objects based on an input expression.
I am successfully filtering the collection when the expression evaluates top-level, primitive fields in the RootObject.
The SpEL Collection Selection feature returns a filtered collection of the RootObjects based on an expression for the key, label, and/or type in the RootObject. This case is working fine.

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariable("collection", collection);
String selectionExpression = "#collection.?[key matches 'foo|foo2|foo3']";
```

My problem is how to filter the original collection to return a collection of RootObjects based on evaluating fields in the OtherObject which are in the values list in the RootObject?
i.e., return all RootObjects that have a list item in RootObject.values where OtherObject.name == foo or OtherObject.count > 10 or OtherObject.isSelected == true.

The collection objects look something like these:

```
public class RootObject {

    String key;
    String label;
    String type;
    List<OtherObject> values;

    public RootObject() {}

    public RootObject(String key, String label, String type, List<OtherObject> values) {
        this.key = key;
        this.label = label;
        this.type = type;
        this.values = values;
    }
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    } 
    public List<OtherObject> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
    public void setValues(List<OtherObject> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}


public class OtherObject {
    private String name;
    private String label;
    private Integer count;
    private Integer totalCount;
    private Boolean isSelected;

    public OtherObject() {}

    public OtherObject(String name, String label, int count, int totalCount, boolean isSelected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.label = label;
        this.setCount(count);
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public Integer getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public Integer getTotalCount() {
        return this.totalCount;
    }
    public void setTotalCount(Integer totalCount) {
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
    }
    public Boolean getIsSelected() {
        return this.isSelected;
    }
    public void setIsSelected(Boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in pure SpEL; you can implement it in Java and register a [custom SpEL function](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-ref-functions).

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking to do two projections. Within the collection of root objects, you want to project to find those root objects where within its set of values, the projection of criteria you want aren't empty.

```
#collection.?[!(values.?[name == 'foo' or count > 10 or isSelected == true].isEmpty())]
```

A projection just makes another list, and you can project based on any boolean expression. And inside a projection, you can continue to use SpEL to figure out that boolean expression, including another projection. You just have to keep in mind that the projection returns a list, whereas the projection criteria needs to be a boolean, so you need to actually check the condition that you're looking for (in this case, that the list is not empty).

Here's the test I did to demonstrate to myself that in fact that it was the right syntax and worked correctly:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final OtherObject otherFooOneNotSelected = new OtherObject("foo", "", 1, 1, false);
    final OtherObject otherBarOneNotSelected = new OtherObject("bar", "", 1, 1, false);
    final OtherObject otherFooTwelveNotSelected = new OtherObject("foo", "", 12, 12, false);
    final OtherObject otherBarTwelveNotSelected = new OtherObject("bar", "", 12, 12, false);
    final OtherObject otherFooOneSelected = new OtherObject("foo", "", 1, 1, true);
    final OtherObject otherBarOneSelected = new OtherObject("bar", "", 1, 1, true);
    final OtherObject otherFooTwelveSelected = new OtherObject("foo", "", 12, 12, true);
    final OtherObject otherBarTwelveSelected = new OtherObject("bar", "", 12, 12, true);
    final RootObject rootNoValues = new RootObject("noValues", "", "", Collections.<OtherObject>emptyList());
    final RootObject rootFooOneNotSelected = new RootObject("rootFooOneNotSelected", "", "", Collections.singletonList(otherFooOneNotSelected));
    final RootObject rootBarOneNotSelected = new RootObject("rootBarOneNotSelected", "", "", Collections.singletonList(otherBarOneNotSelected));
    final RootObject rootBarTwelveNotSelected = new RootObject("rootBarTwelveNotSelected", "", "", Collections.singletonList(otherBarTwelveNotSelected));
    final RootObject rootAllValues = new RootObject("allValues", "", "", Arrays.asList(
            otherFooOneNotSelected,
            otherBarOneNotSelected,
            otherFooTwelveNotSelected,
            otherBarTwelveNotSelected,
            otherFooOneSelected,
            otherBarOneSelected,
            otherFooTwelveSelected,
            otherBarTwelveSelected));
    final Collection<RootObject> collection = Arrays.asList(rootNoValues, rootFooOneNotSelected, rootBarOneNotSelected, rootBarTwelveNotSelected, rootAllValues);

    final ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    final StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.setVariable("collection", collection);
    final String selectionExpression = "#collection.?[!(values.?[name == 'foo' or count > 10 or isSelected == true].isEmpty())]";
    final List<?> result = (List<?>) parser.parseExpression(selectionExpression).getValue(context);
    assertEquals("Result", Arrays.asList(rootFooOneNotSelected, rootBarTwelveNotSelected, rootAllValues), result);
}
```